# Dryer not drying properly

Tags: dryer, appliances

I have a dryer that is not drying properly. You have to run the load 3-4 times to get it dry. Here are some things I have checked:

- It is heating up properly
- The vents are clean (from the vent trap, through the dryer, all the way to the exit of the house)
- Made sure I could feel a decent amount of air coming out of house
- It is spinning properly
- Set it to timer mode (80 minutes) to ensure it was not a moisture sensor

Everything I am finding online is one of these problems, but I can't find anything beyond that. I also changed the timer switch on the unit a while back, not sure if it was the same time this issue started, but considering I tried both the auto-dry and timed mode - it shouldn't be the timer switch - right?

- Make: GE
- Model: GTDX100EM1WW
- Power source: Electric 220v

Got any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe the thermostat? If the thermostat isn't working correctly then it will start to heat up but cycle "off" too much so that the air doesn't get as hot as it should.

Comment: When you say "*The vents are clean*". Do you know because you opened everything up and cleaned it, or are you basing it on the fact that you "*could feel a decent amount of air coming out of house*"?

Comment: Opened it up all the way through and made sure. Took the dryer apart and shined a light through every price of vent. I do have another theory though and I am testing. I will report back.

Comment: Often the problem is with the washing machine not removing water during the drain and spin cycle. I had a hair pin stuck in the pump that slowed the extraction process and left clothes more water laden. This led to much longer drying times